# PHP exec "unable to fork" intermittent error on CentOS VPS

Tags: centos, nginx, php, memory, openssl

Using:

```
PHP 5.5.10
nginx 1.5.10
Centos 6.5

a xen-based 4GB VPS
```

My site uses encrypted paypal buttons.  This encryption is done by the following code:

```
$openssl_cmd = "($OPENSSL smime -sign -signer $MY_CERT_FILE -inkey $MY_KEY_FILE " .
               "-outform der -nodetach -binary <<_EOF_\n$data\n_EOF_\n) | " .
               "$OPENSSL smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE";

exec($openssl_cmd, $output, $error);
```

A couple of times now (a few days apart) the buttons have started to fail to encode.  If I run "service php-fpm restart" then everything is fine again.

This is the error given:

```
PHP Warning:  exec(): Unable to fork [(/usr/bin/openssl smime -sign 
    -signer /var/www/my-pubcert.pem -inkey /var/www/my-prvkey.pem -outform der 
    -nodetach -binary <datasnipped>) | /usr/bin/openssl smime -encrypt -des3 
    -binary -outform pem /var/www/paypal_cert.pem]
```

Once it happens it seems to happen constantly until I restart php-fpm.

Any ideas what route I should go down to debug/fix this?

Thanks

Comment: How many child processes do you spawn with php-fpm and what is your maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the PHP processes start using a lot of memory at some point (you can check that in top, press M to sort the processes by memory). Try setting "pm.max_requests = 100" or, anyway, a much lower value of what you have now (or, around 100 or so if it is 0, which means infinite).

By the way, a much better approach to your encryption would be to use the PHP OpenSSL library rather than executing the command line interface of OpenSSL.

**Edit:**

At your request (even if it is partially off-topic), you can find documentation and example code for the 2 OpenSSL functions in PHP [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-encrypt.php). You may need to recompile PHP with OpenSSL support or install the required module (normally it should have it built in).

Comment: I would very much rather do this inside PHP than using exec - could you link me to some example code to get me started?  Thanks!

In the meantime I've just discovered the php-fpm status page, so I will be keeping an eye on that and will see what's going on there.

Comment: Thanks for those links.  I've implemented that now and done some simple ab benchmarking and the php implementation slows the page from 100ms average to 500ms, so I might have to discount that option.  A shame, but I guess not entirely unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at how many file handles you have open, and what the max is set to. `sysctl fs.file-nr` is a good place to start. If the first number is close to the last, you're running out of file handles! you can up them by setting it in systcl.conf, or by `sysctl -w fs.file-max=100000`. If this is the case, I'd look elsewhere in your code for why file handles anrent being closed.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP 5.3.3 on CentOS 6.3 this was an error I ran across because the webserver user didn't have a valid shell. Adding .bashrc to the nginx user's home directory fixed it for us.

See answer as this dupe question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648949/php-warning-exec-unable-to-fork/24517481#24517481

Comment: Downvote with no comment?